# How to use MicrosoftMvcValidation with jQuery.Ajax in ASP.net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

> using asp.net mvc2, Data Annotations,
>   MicrosoftAjax.js,MicrosoftMvcValidation.js,
>   jquery for ajax

I have contact form and i am using Data Annotations for the `ContactFormModel`.
I add this line `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` to top of the form.

When i click the submit button client validation works perfectly. Now i have changed my mind and want to post the form with jQuery.Ajax.

This time i want to accomplish this.

1. Click submit button.
2. MicrosoftMVCValidation does the client validation and renders the errors on the clientside.
3. If Model is valid i meant if the validation passed i want my jQuery ajax to get involved.

But when i clicked the submit button both ajax post and mvc client validation works.
How can i get the things in right order.

1.Mvc Client validation
2. Then jQuery.Ajax Post.

Answer (score 1):

```
            var myForm = $("#MainForm");
            var formContext = myForm[0]['__MVC_FormValidation'];
            var errors;
            if (formContext) {
                // validate the form
                errors = formContext.validate("submit");
            }
            if (!formContext || errors.length == 0) {
                // no errors so submit to server
                ...
            }
```